# How to update sprite position in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I've been trying to get this working for ages and have looked at other questions but I still can't do it.
I'm trying to make the sprite move when the arrow keys are pressed but nothing is happening.
The sprite does get drawn but thats it.
Heres the code.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from data import *


def main():
    def draw_map(Map):
        for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
            #loop through each column in the row
            for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
                #draw the resource at that position in the tilemap, using the correct colour
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours[Map[row][column]], (column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE,TILESIZE,TILESIZE))
    def stop():
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    tilemap = [
               [white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white],
               [white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white],
               [white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white],
               [white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white],
               [white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white],
               [white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white],
               [white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white],
               [white, white, white, white, white, blue, blue, white, white, white],
               [white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white, white],
               [green, green, green, green, green, green, green, green, green, green]
              ] 

    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()

    class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    class Player(Entity):
        def __init__(self):
            Entity.__init__(self)
            self.playerx = 50
            self.playery = 50
            self.image = pygame.image.load("p3_front.png")
            self.rect = Rect(self.playerx, self.playery, 66, 92)

    player = Player()
    pygame.init()

    # Set the width and height of the screen 
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

    # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    entities.add(player)

    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    while True:
        # ALL EVENT PROCESSING SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT
        for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
                stop()
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]: player.playery -= 3  
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]: player.playery += 3
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: player.playerx -= 3
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: player.playerx += 3

        # ALL EVENT PROCESSING SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT


        # ALL GAME LOGIC SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT

        # ALL GAME LOGIC SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT



        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT

        # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
        # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
        screen.fill(white)
        draw_map(tilemap)
        entities.update()
        entities.draw(screen)

        # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

        # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
        pygame.display.flip()

        # Limit to 20 frames per second
        clock.tick(20)

    stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Exactly which part of your code isn't working? and what is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: sshashank124's answer fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `entities.update()` method simply calls the `update` method of its individual classes, therefore, you actually have to create a method in your `Player` class that updates the sprite as you want it to. For the `Player` class, it would probably look like:

```
class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.playerx = 50
        self.playery = 50
        self.image = pygame.image.load("p3_front.png")
        self.rect = Rect(self.playerx, self.playery, 66, 92)

    def update(self):
        self.rect = Rect(self.playerx, self.playery, 66, 92)
```

I suggest you check [this link](http://floppsie.comp.glam.ac.uk/Glamorgan/gaius/games/8.html) out. It gives a great explanation on the workings of `sprites` in `pygame`.